# Slow counting of points in polygon in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am working on a plugin to count the point in polygons by PyQGIS in QGIS 3.4, and I found that compared to the same function in QGIS 2.18, it is very slow. I do not know the reason. My code is listed as follows.

```
processing.run("qgis:countpointsinpolygon",{'POLYGONS':mesh_layer,'POINTS':select_crash_layer,'WEIGHT':None,'CLASSFIELD':None,'FIELD':'Count','OUTPUT':category_mesh_layer})
```

I used this function to calculate approximate 25000 points to 3761 polygons to find how many points in each polygon. I realized it in QGIS 2.18 within 10 s. However, in QGIS 3.4 it needs more than 5 minutes.

Comment: You should also specify if you are using a point to find polygon, or a polygon to find points.

Comment: I used this function to calculate approximate 25000 points to 3761 polygons to find how many points in each polygon.  I realized it in QGIS 2.18 within 10 s. However, in QGIS 3.4 it needs more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Please edit your question (not as a comment) and add more information, such as how much slower, how many points and polygons, whether you have built spatial indexes, what format your data is.